# I was marked as a help vampire and want to dispute it

Tags: discussion, support

I was trying to answer [Viewing PDF in browser (Firefox) on Ubuntu 9.04](https://superuser.com/questions/70329/viewing-pdf-in-browser-firefox-on-ubuntu-9-04) when I found my account had been blocked. Reasons cited were

- users who can't be bothered to form sentences
- users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
- users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do
- downvotes from other users

I've only asked [two](https://superuser.com/questions/458883/cant-download-zip-from-a-shared-dropbox) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/458982/how-to-copy-files-from-linux-to-windows-with-rdp) on this stackexchange site, with scores 0 and 1. Given [one answer](https://superuser.com/questions/13929/backing-up-google-chrome/257260#257260). All 3 Q&A's use proper English; I write in the question some of the results of already Googling; and I think it's clear what I'm trying to do (in the case of the questions).

I'd like to be able to participate in this as well as the other SE sites I'm a part of.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what happens when you're trying to post?

Comment: @Sathya Sorry, I can't reproduce the error now because @ nhinkle fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ban also takes into account deleted answers, of which you have 3, each of which was identical, marked as spam, and downvoted. At present, you don't have any upvoted answers. The answer ban and question ban are separate from each other, so from the perspective of answers, your account is probably slightly too far into the negative end.

It looks like your triple-post may have just been a case of overzealous answering of similar questions, so I'm going to clear the spam flags on those and it should give you some reputation back. Let us know if that lets you answer questions again.

Comment: Thank you @nhinkle.

Comment: It did let me answer the question.

Comment: Could you point me to the question that the deleted answers were on please? I'm struggling to remember what that was.

Comment: @isomorphismes [1](http://superuser.com/questions/244325/how-to-restore-the-window-of-tabs-crashed-1-day-ago-in-google-chrome/383843#383843), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/341068/how-can-i-load-my-last-tabs-into-chrome-using-last-tabs-last-session-files/383861#383861), [3](http://superuser.com/questions/342484/how-to-restore-correct-session-tabs-when-google-chrome-crashes/383864#383864).

Comment: @isomorphismes in the future, please take care to not repost the same answer many times like that. Glad it fixed the problem for you this time.

Comment: @nhinkle Ah, looking at these now they make less sense and look more spammy than I thought at the time. If it's ok with you I'm going to edit and undelete them because I still want anyone who lands from google to see Lo Sauer's application. It's saved me untold frustration (and it's not uncommon to lose all tabs in a crash due to imperfect session management in popular browsers).